# rails 3 form_tag w/ remote doesn't send submit details

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

This form works 100% when using the normal non-remote request.  However when I set remote => true it is not longer sending the submit value.  Should I do this completely differently, or is there something I'm missing?

```
<%= form_tag [voteable, Vote.new], :remote => true do |f| %>
    <strong class="votes_balance"><%= voteable.votes_for - voteable.votes_against %></strong>
    <%= submit_tag :up, { :name => "thumb_direction", :class => "vote_up" } %>
    <%= submit_tag :down, { :name => "thumb_direction", :class => "vote_down" } %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :voteable_type, voteable.class %>
<% end %>
```

## params

```
authenticity_token  /8Dkx/EQc+VqgZd8f/eoWevm8AIgOwK0rzXqlGUzDUA=
utf8    ✓
voteable_type   Article
```

## should send

```
authenticity_token  /8Dkx/EQc+VqgZd8f/eoWevm8AIgOwK0rzXqlGUzDUA=
utf8    ✓
voteable_type   Article
thumb_direction     up
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a more concise way, I also tried briefly the button_to method but couldn't figure out how to squeeze it all in.

```
<div id="votes" class="thumbs_up">

    <%= form_tag [voteable, Vote.new], :remote => true do |f| %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :voteable_type, voteable.class %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :thumb_direction, "up" %>
        <%= submit_tag :up, { :class => "vote_up" } %>
    <% end %>

    <strong class="votes_balance"><%= voteable.votes_for - voteable.votes_against %></strong>

    <%= form_tag [voteable, Vote.new], :remote => true do |f| %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :voteable_type, voteable.class %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :thumb_direction, "down" %>
        <%= submit_tag :down, { :class => "vote_down" } %>
    <% end %>

</div>
```